# Running cherrypy app on AWS: socket could not be created

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cherrypy, web-frameworks

I have developed a small web app on my Windows PC and tested it locally.
Then I wanted to transfer it to an AWS Ubuntu 18 instance.

For the sake of brevity, the app processes a form from a webpage and redirects a user to the page with the result. The contents of the app do not really matter, since the error occurs before you can interact with it.

I have not encountered any issues running it locally (i.e. the same code as below, w/out `cherrypy.config.update`).

```
import cherrypy
import os
filepath = os.getcwd()

class MyApp(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        with open('./index.html', 'r') as f:
            text = f.read()
        return text
    @cherrypy.expose
    def process_filled_form(self, field1, field2):
        out = filed1+field2
        return(out)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = {"/folder": {"tools.staticdir.on": True,
                        "tools.staticdir.dir": os.path.join(filepath, "folder")}}
    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
                            'server.socket_port': 9028,})
    cherrypy.quickstart(MyApp(), '/', config)
```

But when I try to make the app public on an AWS instance, I get the following error:

```
[06/Mar/2021:06:25:12] ENGINE Listening for SIGTERM.
[06/Mar/2021:06:25:12] ENGINE Listening for SIGHUP.
[06/Mar/2021:06:25:12] ENGINE Listening for SIGUSR1.
[06/Mar/2021:06:25:12] ENGINE Bus STARTING
[06/Mar/2021:06:25:12] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
[06/Mar/2021:06:25:12] ENGINE Error in HTTP server: shutting down
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/user_app/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cherrypy/process/servers.py", line 225, in _start_http_thread
    self.httpserver.start()
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/user_app/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cheroot/server.py", line 1836, in start
    self.prepare()
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/user_app/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cheroot/server.py", line 1791, in prepare
    raise socket.error(msg)
OSError: No socket could be created -- (('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', 9028): [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address)

[06/Mar/2021:06:25:12] ENGINE Bus STOPPING
[06/Mar/2021:06:25:12] ENGINE HTTP Server cherrypy._cpwsgi_server.CPWSGIServer(('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', 9028)) already shut down
[06/Mar/2021:06:25:12] ENGINE Stopped thread 'Autoreloader'.
[06/Mar/2021:06:25:12] ENGINE Bus STOPPED
[06/Mar/2021:06:25:12] ENGINE Bus EXITING
[06/Mar/2021:06:25:12] ENGINE Bus EXITED
```

Changing the socket does not affect anything. The app produces no errors when launched locally on AWS.
I am totally new to anything web-related, so the problem might be smt very obvious. Perhaps, I am missing something in the config, or `quickstart` may not be the right option to launch the app.
Please help

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are binding to a wrong address.

In you `config.update` call, modify the `socket_host` value to `0.0.0.0`:

```
cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
                        'server.socket_port': 9028,})
```

That should allow your app to listen for requests on all the network addresses that are available in your host.

Comment: I tried this, but the result is the same as running it locally. My friends told me I need to set up nginx. I was hoping it could be solved wout any extra server software, but apparently, it is not the case.